# does the here.com REST API support indoor positioning

Tags: rest, here-api

I've downloaded the getting started guides, and created a developer account to get access to the docs.  All the docs I can find related to **indoor positioning** indicate Android/iOS are supported, but I can't find any documentation to use the REST API for indoor positioning.

My goal is to use here.com indoor positioning from an ESP32/micropython based device, using the same REST methods that I'm sure the mobile apps use to send wifi/BlueTooth Beacon signal data to the REST API.

is this supported, and is there documentation for it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the REST call  :

```
https://pos.api.here.com/positioning/v1/locate?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Check this [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/topics/example-wlan.html) for an example

Comment: Thanks Shruti Kuber, that looks like its for WLAN positioning.  Here Indoor positioning uses Bluetooth beacons + wifi signal strength (which I don't see in that POST data). 
 Looking for the REST documenttion to implement what is described here: 
 https://developer.here.com/documentation/tracking/topics/tips-for-data-accuracy-indoor.html

Comment: @3z33etm did you find any solution? We currently have kind of the same problem, since the Flutter HERE SDK does not seem to support indoor positioning yet. So we would have to use a rest API for that.